# Problems sync Gradle with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I download android play location master project from `github` for reading project and working with fused location provider but I cant sync this project. I didn't use `Kotlin` before and the project always return `connection timed out: connect`. I searched two days but I couldn't resolve problem. In Kotlin updates part in settings, my current Kotlin plugin version is 1.2.71-release-Studio3.2-1 is set.

How to solve this problems?

Another note, I connect from Iran country and for this I set proxy in settings but my settings is correct and when I checked  connection, everything is OK.

Comment: i donno if thats gonna help you or not, but you can try changing your VPN , some times it works !

Comment: Thanks for your reply but don't effect on my sync project .

Comment: where is the sync Gradle error log? can you provide it?